# Adding a percentage change column with a LOOP

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Year': [2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008],
    'Pop': [94,98,100,103,108,109,105,101]})
```

I am trying to create a column with the percentage changes relative to the previous year. With the simple formula of change relative to the previous year:
`[Year(i)/Year(i-1)]-1`.

I know that I can do that with `pct_change()`, but I would like to know how to do it with a LOOP that iritates the change formula and creates a new column.

I tried this

```
for i in df['Pop']:
    df['Pop%'] = df['Pop'].iloc[i+1] / df['Pop'].iloc[i] - 1
    if i == len(df.Pop):
        break
```

but it didn't work and gave the error "single positional indexer is out-of-bounds".

Comment: Your `i` is the value, not the position.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution:

```
values = []
previous = float('nan')
for value in df['Pop']:
    values.append(value/previous-1)
    previous = value
values
```

output:

```
[nan,
 0.042553191489361764,
 0.020408163265306145,
 0.030000000000000027,
 0.04854368932038833,
 0.0092592592592593,
 -0.03669724770642202,
 -0.03809523809523807]
```

As a vectorial operation, this would be:

```
df['Pop']/df['Pop'].shift()-1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just adjust your code as the following:

```
for i in df['Pop'].index:
    if i==0:
        pass
    df['Pop%'].iloc[i] = df['Pop'].iloc[i] / df['Pop'].iloc[i-1] - 1
    if i == 1+len(df.Pop):
        break
```

[image]

Updating values as df['Pop%'] = df['Pop'].iloc[i+1] / df['Pop'].iloc[i] - 1 changes every row each time with the same value.And since you can't use this formula for the row 0 you should exclude that.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try list comprehension:

```
df['Pop%']=[(df['Pop'].iat[x]/df['Pop'].iat[x-1])-1 if x!=0 else float('NaN') for x in range(len(df))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Series.iteritems()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iteritems.html) to iterate over the Pandas series of `Pop` column and set up the column values of new column `Pop%` within the loop, as follows:

```
import numpy as np

pop_prev = np.nan
for i, pop in df['Pop'].iteritems():
    df.loc[i, 'Pop%'] = pop / pop_prev - 1
    pop_prev = pop
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   Year  Pop      Pop%
0  2001   94       NaN
1  2002   98  0.042553
2  2003  100  0.020408
3  2004  103  0.030000
4  2005  108  0.048544
5  2006  109  0.009259
6  2007  105 -0.036697
7  2008  101 -0.038095
```

However, it is strongly recommended to use the vectorized function [`Series.pct_change()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.pct_change.html) instead of the looping here:

```
df['Pop%_2'] = df['Pop'].pct_change()
```

```
print(df)

   Year  Pop      Pop%    Pop%_2
0  2001   94       NaN       NaN
1  2002   98  0.042553  0.042553
2  2003  100  0.020408  0.020408
3  2004  103  0.030000  0.030000
4  2005  108  0.048544  0.048544
5  2006  109  0.009259  0.009259
6  2007  105 -0.036697 -0.036697
7  2008  101 -0.038095 -0.038095
```

Same results and the code is much simpler and run much faster.